# Can I use Ubuntu installers partition tool (Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I have laptop less than year old with preinstalled Windows 8 (now updated to 8.1). I'd like to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows, I have read many instructions on web and watched tutorials on Youtube, but still one question remains.

I have Hp laptop, with 'local disk (C:)' and 'RECOVERY (D:)'. I would like to avoid manual partitioning because I don't have the confidence to mess with that :). I've seen in the instructions on web that I could use the 'Install alongside Windows' option and it would create the partitions automatically, but all the examples are having Windows with only C: disk.

So the question is: will it make any difference to have also the D: disk? Can I use the 'Install alongside Windows' option?

(I've booted my laptop already from LiveUSB and selected the Try Ubuntu, and checked that I had the 'Install alongside Windows' option visible, just didn't have the guts to do it then :)..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,"Install alongside Windows" option will make the D drive to loss it's files or even the whole partition also.

So first partition the disk and fomat it to ext4 partition using Gparted partition Editor.Then run the Ubuntu installer and then choose "something else" option to manually install Ubuntu on a selected ext4 partition.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more thing, I checked couple tutorials: after shrinking the disk on windows and running the installer after 'something else' option, I need to create the swap area and another logical partition that is mounted to '/'. Is that enough? Another tutorial told to create one more logical partition to be mounted to '/home', do I need to do that also?

Comment: shrink the partition you want.From that unallocated space create an ext4 partition.Close gparted and run the installer.After choosing the ext4 partition in the something else option,it prompts you to specify the size of [swap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) partition.Give the size,after that a swap partition was **automatically** created in extended partition.